# NullException on Bitmap ,bitmaps is getting null value

Tags: image, file, indexing, android-recyclerview, bitmap

- 

> I'm trying to get multiple images from the gallery, show it in >`Recyclerview`, and sending it to server but showing this error >Here's my code to write the images to file,the error is at the >initialization of inputstream

---

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("Data any THING", String.valueOf(data));
        if (requestCode == ImagePicker.IMAGE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            List<String> mPaths = data.getStringArrayListExtra(ImagePicker.EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH);
            Log.d("mPaths MainActivity", String.valueOf(mPaths));
            
                for (int i = 0; i < mPaths.size(); i++) {
                    files.add(new File(mPaths.get(i)));

                 
                }
                if (inputStream==null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
                        try {
                        

                            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile( files.get(i)));
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Inputstream"+String.valueOf(inputStream), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            bitmaps = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                            Log.e("File", String.valueOf(files));
                            Log.e("stream", String.valueOf(inputStream));
                            editText.setText(String.valueOf(files)+String.valueOf(inputStream));
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.d("DATASSSSSSSSSSSTTTT", String.valueOf(data.getData()));
                        Log.e("IMages From Stream", String.valueOf(bitmaps));
                        Log.d("Images from Steam", String.valueOf(bitmaps));
                        recyclerAdapter.fileMOthod(files);
                        if (bitmaps != null) {
                            resizeIMagestoAdapter();
                            imageResize(bitmaps);
                        } else {
                        }
                        }
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `files` array has only indices 0 to `files.size()-1`, but your `i` variable goes from 0 to `files.size()` in the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.size()+1; i++)
```

Therefore, `files.get(i)` fails with the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

`Index: 2, Size: 2` means that the size of `files` is 2 (it has only indices 0 and 1), but you are trying to access index 2.

Comment: @Edwin I suggest you to get familiar with basic Java before getting into Android :) Now, you should dive into debugging and find out which variable is null and why is it so. And you could also mark my answer as solution if it helped with the original problem.

Comment: I'm getting null in inputstream